# Display two clocks in two different time zones in the notification bar

Tags: notification-bar, clock, time-zones

How can I display two clocks in two different time zones in the notification bar? By default, only one time is displayed at the top left of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using tasker [Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and a plugin called Text Inject [Xposed Repo Link](https://repo.xposed.info/module/com.chaimchaikin.textinject) you will need to be rooted and have Xposed installed.

Instructions:

1. Setup a profile in Tasker that runs every 2 minutes. (Smallest interval)
2. Set the task to Parse Format Date/Time
3. Input should be Now.
4. Output should be h:mm a z
5. Formatted Variable Name set to whatever you want. Ex. %TimeOffset
6. Offset should be set to Hours and set the amount of hours needed.
7. Set a task to set TextInject Variable to the variable setup in previous task. Ex. TimeOffset = %TimeOffset
8. In TextInject set statusbar time to #TimeOffset and parse as time
   Done

Answer (score 2):

I found a better solution, but leaving my original answer in case someone wants to format the statusbar differently.

Using Xposed as well as before. There is a Module called xDualStatusClock which makes it very simple to just choose the timezone and it works.
XDualStatusclock - http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.jukka666.xdualstatusclock

Comment: Thanks for the update!